# Python: Check which tuple item string ends with, if it ends with one at all

Tags: python, loops, search, tuples

In python you can check if a string ends with any item in a tuple  with `string.endswith(tuple)`, but is there a simple way to find out which item in that tuple it ends with (if it ends with one at all) without having to loop through the tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible withtout a loop. You can create a generator expression, like this

```
next((suffix for suffix in suffix_tuple if input_string.endswith(suffix)), None)
```

For example,

```
suffix_tuple, input_string = ("s", "r", "t"), "clear"
next((suffix for suffix in suffix_tuple if input_string.endswith(suffix)), None)
# r
```

Since the default value is `None`, if no string in `suffix_tuple` matches, it will return `None`.